# How to prevent IPython notebook script pausing when the screen locks

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to run an IPython notebook script that will take several hours to complete (processing of ~40 movies). However the script pauses when the screen locks and then resumes execution when I login to my account.. Is there anyway to prevent the IPython script from pausing while the screen is locked?

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it took a bit of googling, but if it's any help to anyone you can prevent your Mac from going to sleep by opening terminal and typing pmset noidle, which will tell the power management utility to temporarily disable sleep.